# Creating a Windows Runtime Component that uses Bing Maps

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bing-maps, winmd

I am trying to create a Windows Runtime Component that uses Bing Maps.  Since The Bing Maps libraries are WinMD based, I also need to create my own WinMD.  Sadly, there seems to be a conflict betweem the VCLibs WinMD that is required by Bing Maps and the Windows WinMD that is required to create any visual components.  When I compile, I get the following error.

> Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation.Point' was found in multiple referenced winmd files. Please remove either 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\platform.winmd' or 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd' from the list of referenced files.

As I cannot remove either of those references (they are both used in my library), I find myself unable to create my component.

Any ideas how I could fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have something to do with the native C++ libraries not supporting "Any CPU". Try setting the build platform by going to Build -> Configuration Manager and set the platform of your project to x86. Then try building the project to see if you still get this error.